# Update command using Npgsql postgres and C#

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have created a search form to locate a record based on a search value called license ID. I am able to pull the all the fields for that value. My question is I am trying to update any field for that record, example if I want to update the address field or the zip code field which all these field values are in text boxes.  I get an syntax error at or near ""Lname"". Lname is the database field name for last name. This project is just a test project to get familiar with Postgres. Here is my source code. I am not sure what the problems is, the field name is correctly specified.

```
 private void UpdateRecord()
    {
        try
        {
            NpgsqlConnection conn = Connection.getConnection();
            conn.Open();

            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("update info set \"Fname\" = :FirstName, set \"Lname\" = :LastName, set \"Address\" = :Address," +
                "set \"City\" = :City, set \"State\" = State, set \"Zip\" = :Zip," + 
                "set \"PhoneNumber\" = :PhoneNumber where \"LicenceNumber\" = '" + LicenseID + "' ;", conn);

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("FirstName", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("LastName", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("Address", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("City", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("State", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("Zip", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("PhoneNumber", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text));
            cmd.Parameters[0].Value = txtFirstName.Text;
            cmd.Parameters[1].Value = txtLastName.Text;
            cmd.Parameters[2].Value = txtAddress.Text;
            cmd.Parameters[3].Value = txtCity.Text;
            cmd.Parameters[4].Value = cboState.Text;
            cmd.Parameters[5].Value = txtZip.Text;
            cmd.Parameters[6].Value = mtxtPhoneNumber.Text;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: in your schema, is "lanme" lowercase, uppercase, or mixed case.  This matters in postgre.

Comment: The field is Lname in the schema. Mixed case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only need "set" once per command.

```
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("update info set \"Fname\" = :FirstName, \"Lname\" = :LastName, \"Address\" = :Address," +
                "\"City\" = :City, \"State\" = State, \"Zip\" = :Zip," + 
                "\"PhoneNumber\" = :PhoneNumber where \"LicenceNumber\" = '" + LicenseID + "' ;", conn);
```