# update query not working vb net

Tags: sql, vb.net, postgresql, npgsql

When I try to update the database using the following query, I receive the message *"update successful"*, but it's not true, my data is still the same as before.

```vb
Public Function alterar() As Boolean
    Dim cd As New npgSqlCommand
    Dim query As String = ""

    Try
       query &= "UPDATE [Caixa] SET Recibo = '" & iRecibo & "' ,  CentroCusto = '" & sCentroCusto & "' ,  Data = '" & sData & "' , Dia = '" & sDia & "' , _
       Mes ='" & sMes & "', Ano = '" & sAno & "' , CentroCustoResumo = '" & sCentroCustoResumo & "' , CodSubCentroCusto ='" & sCodSubCentroCusto & "', _
        DescSubCentroCusto ='" & sDescSubCentroCusto & "', Eventos ='" & sEventos & "', Historico = '" & sHistorico & "' , _
       Dinheiro = '" & sDinheiro & "', Cheque = '" & sCheque & "', Cartao = '" & sCartao & "', DepositoDireto = '" & sDepositoDireto & "', _
       Total ='" & sTotal &  "' WHERE Recibo = '" & iRecibo.ToString()

        If Conexao.NonQuery(cd) Then
            sStatus = "O Recibo " & iRecibo & " foi alterado com sucesso!"
            Return True
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        sStatus = ex.Message
    End Try
    Return True
End Function

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim c As New Caixa()
    Try
        If TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
            c.Recibo = CInt(TextBox1.Text)

            If c.excluir() Then
                MessageBox.Show(c.Status)
                CaixaLoad()
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(c.Status)
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Nenhum registro selecionado!")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        'MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

What's the problem with my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Fixing your code

Try the following code, (1) i used `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` instead of `Conexao.NonQuery(cd)` also (2) the `query` string was not assigned to `cmd` command, and (3) `[]` brackets are not used in postgresql you have to use double quotes if needed. (4) it is recommended to use `Using` when working with npgsqlcommand Class

```
Public Function alterar() As Boolean

    Dim query As String = ""
    Try

       query = "UPDATE Caixa SET Recibo = '" & iRecibo & "' ,  CentroCusto = '" & sCentroCusto & "' ,  Data = '" & sData & "' , Dia = '" & sDia & "' , " &  _
       "Mes ='" & sMes & "', Ano = '" & sAno & "' , CentroCustoResumo = '" & sCentroCustoResumo & "' , CodSubCentroCusto ='" & sCodSubCentroCusto & "', " &  _
       "DescSubCentroCusto ='" & sDescSubCentroCusto & "', Eventos ='" & sEventos & "', Historico = '" & sHistorico & "' , " & _
       "Dinheiro = '" & sDinheiro & "', Cheque = '" & sCheque & "', Cartao = '" & sCartao & "', DepositoDireto = '" & sDepositoDireto & "', " & _
       "Total ='" & sTotal &  "' WHERE Recibo = '" & iRecibo.ToString & "'"

        Using cmd As New npgSqlCommand

            cmd.CommandText = query
            cmd.Connection = conn 

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            sStatus = "O Recibo " & iRecibo & " foi alterado com sucesso!"

        End Using

        Return True



    Catch ex As Exception
        sStatus = ex.Message
        Return False
    End Try

End Function
```

## Parameterized query

it is recommended to use parameterized queries for better security *(more secure against sql injection)* and better performance, you can follow these similar question for more information:

- [Update command using Npgsql postgres and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287396/update-command-using-npgsql-postgres-and-c-sharp)

**References**

- [Npgsql Documentation](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/index.html)
- [Quoting columns with spaces in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/118059/quoting-columns-with-spaces-in-postgresql)

Comment: @Leogreen i didn't change anything in the query syntax, but i will check it.

Comment: 42601 unterminated quoted string at or nearr " the field i've selected to update"

Comment: @Leogreen i removed quotes because there is no columns name with spaces try it now

Comment: Have you even tried yourself to debug, SO isnt a code writing service... so far you have made out..

Comment: still the same error  
42601 unterminated quoted string at or nearr " the field i've selected to update"

Comment: @leogreen we missed the last quote, just add `& "'"` at the end of the query. Check the answer update